# Sending folder via network

Tags: file, compression

I have made file sending program. 
Now tring to add folder sending feature.
So I am considering two ways.

1. Traverse every child folders and send each file separately.
2. Merge all child folders into one single file and send one big file

2 choice is far better for performance. but it maybe needs temporary space for merging file. 
Can I do second way without temporary file and space ? or Is there better solution for this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution for my question. Travesing every sub files/folder and send that each time is right way. Making one merging file requires space/time and that will cause annoyance for user. I have used boost::filesysme's travese feature. It iw really fast and easy to use.